# Unordered List Navigation Bar: How to I make some buttons go to the right of the navigation page?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am making a simple navigation bar at the top with CSS and HTML (some code I have)

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Settings</li>
    <!--...-->
</ul>
```

and so on with a little CSS `display:inline` magic. That all works fine, except I want to move some of the links, like "Settings," to the other side of the navigation bar and replace it with a little icon. However, I cannot find how to do this. I've tried `float:right` and applying it to some of the list items using `class` and then referencing them through CSS. I've also tried `text-align:right`, but nothing seems to work. **What am I doing wrong and how can I get some of the list items to be on the right side of the navigation bar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this ->**

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdKmH/1/)

I have put the settings and the register on a div and added `float:right` to push it to the right.

If you want a image replace the text with `<img/>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your html looked like exactly but this did the trick for me

```
<div>
    <ul style="list-style: none; display:inline">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li style="display:inline">Contact</li>
        <li style="display:inline; float:right;">Settings</li>
        <li>One More to Make Sure It Works</li>
    </ul>
</div
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9EEF/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just make another unordered list completely. It sounds like what you're trying to do shouldn't be done in the same ul.

There might be a way to do it how you're asking but it seems like making a seperate ul would be the easiest way.

Comment: I tried that and then I added a div with the width set to 100% but it knocked the settings and such onto a new line. What else could I do with the two unordered lists?

Comment: Have you set both unorderedlists/divs with float properties? Along with taking account for the padding/margin, they could be pushing your div/ul to the next line. If not, post up your entire code so I can see  if I can't figure it out.